# A term for a wiki-like website, but without the visitor editing abilities?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, american-english, british-english

What would be the correct term for a website that contains information akin to a wiki, but does not offer the ability for guests and members to edit the content?

I am rather baffled by this. 'Information repository' came across my mind, but it occurred to me that a repository most likely gives the impression that the data is never modified once it has been provided, which is not what I am going for.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might call it a "website".... ;-)

Comment: perhaps *personal wiki*

Comment: But it would be used as a means to help others. There would be practically no personal information on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Encyclopedia**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/encyclopedia):

> a book or set of books containing many articles arranged in alphabetical order that deal either with the whole of human knowledge or with a particular part of it, or a similar set of articles on the internet

Or if you want to stress that it's a website, not a book: **encyclopedic website**. Encyclopedic is an adjective meaning, according to [Cambdridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/encyclopedic):

> covering a large range of knowledge, often in great detail

Attribution:

(Definition of “encyclopedia” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

(Definition of “encyclopedic” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

Comment: Many thanks for providing an adjective. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This entirely depends on what kind of wiki you mean. For Wikipedia, it would be an encyclopedia. For a wiki-faq, it would be an faq. You're asking for a thing-like thing that is not that thing. The *wiki* prefix or word is exactly the part that means it *does* offer the ability for guests and members to edit the content:

#### wiki

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/267577?):

> A type of web page designed so that its content can be edited by anyone who accesses it, using a simplified markup language.

Comment: Hence why I am asking for a term that _isn't_ "wiki."  It merely shares the ultimate goal of a wiki in that it provides vast amounts of information on one or a variety of subjects. You could definitely call it a website, but that sets it apart to no other out there. I'd like an adjective, not a noun.